# Iterating Rows and adding the value from the row above- Python

Tags: python, loops

I have a column that acts as a ledger. The values in each row is either a receipt (positive) and an outbound (negative). I am looking to create an additional column that takes the value from the row above and adds/subracts the current value and gives a total
[image]

Below is the code I have tried, but all it does is write the values into another column:

```
mylist, df["consumption"]= []," " 
for i in range(1, len(thc) + 1):
    j = df.columns.get_loc('Ledger')
    x = (df.iat[i - 1, j])
    mylist.append(x)
df["consumption"] = mylist
```

I would like the consumption column to look like:
[image]

The intent is to use this df to create a forecast and a lined plot tracking consumption.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have a look into the pandas `shift()` function.  This helps with row offsetting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [df.cumsum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)

```
df["consumption"] = df['Ledger'].cumsum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the above data as a 2d array where `id` represent index 0, `transaction` represents index 1, `date` represent index 2 and **`ledger`** represents index value 3.

so we will have an 2-d array structure like

> [ [id1, transaction1, date1, ledger1 ], [id2, transaction2, date2,ledger2 ],.... ]

Now we want to add a new column consumption to each row which will be the sum of current `legder` and previous `ledger` and it will represent the 4th index value for each row.

```
account =  [    [ 0 , "Beg bal2019-2020 ",  " 2019-09-05" , 16875],
                [ 1 , "3072 ",  " 2019-09-05" , -50],
                [ 2 , "30874 ",  " 2019-09-05" , -50],
                [ 3 , "247499 ",  " 2019-09-05" , -50],
           ]

current = 0
for row in account:
    row.append(current + row[3])
    current =row[4]

for i in account:
    print(i)
```

**Output**

```
[0, 'Beg bal2019-2020 ', ' 2019-09-05', 16875, 16875]
[1, '3072 ', ' 2019-09-05', -50, 16825]
[2, '30874 ', ' 2019-09-05', -50, 16775]
[3, '247499 ', ' 2019-09-05', -50, 16725]
```